# Variables visibility in eval

Tags: php

I'm creating a small engine similar to Laravel. I have a small view that processes the code contained in {{ }} as php code in a file that **also contains html**.

I would like variables to be visible in all brackets, not only those in which they were declared.

My renderManager.php:

```
    *...*
    public function replaceCodeInBrackets($codeToReplace)
    {
        $codeToReplace = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/',
            function ($matches) {
                ob_start();

                eval($matches[1]);

                return ob_get_clean();
            },
            $codeToReplace
        );

        return $codeToReplace;
    }
    *...*
```

This is what we provide for the function above in $codeToReplace:

```
<hr>
<h2>{{ echo 'First message'; }}</h2>
*// Output is: First message*
<hr>
<h2>{{ $myVariable = 'Second message'; echo $myVariable; }}</h2>
// Output is: Second message
<hr>
<h2>{{ echo 'Previous variable: ' . $myVariable; }}</h2>
*// Output is: Warning: Undefined variable $myVariable...*
<hr>
```

As you can see the variable is visible only in given brackets. I want it to be visible in others too.
Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Quote manual: _"The code will be executed in the scope of the code calling eval(). Thus any variables defined or changed in the eval() call will remain visible after it terminates."_ - your problem here is that the preg_replace_callback callback function creates its own scope, every time it runs - and so variables from your previous eval calls are not available any more. I don't think there is a really clean way to solve this (but then, using eval for this kind of functionality is _dangerous_ enough to begin with, so it should not even be attempted in the first place ...)